# Issue with tags in RTF Template while validating in BI Publisher

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I have the following rtf template which i am trying to use.

```
<?choose:?>
<?when: COMP_3_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT='' and COMP COMP_2_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT='' ?>
No Letter has been generated for this employee as they were not eligible for a pay or bonus review and did not receive any share awards.

Plan:           <?PLAN_NAME?>
Period:         <?PERIOD_NAME?>
Name:           <?NAME?>
Person Number:  <?PERSON_NUMBER?>
<?end when?>
<?otherwise:?>

<?NAME?>                                            
Person Number : <?PERSON_NUMBER?>
<?CURRENT_JOB?>

Dear <?FIRST_NAME?>,

<?IF: COMP_4_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT=''?>
Pay Review 2016

On this occasion you have not been awarded a salary increase. Your salary will remain at £ <? BASE_SALARY_CURRENT?> per annum.
<?end if?>

<?IF: COMP_4_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT!=''?>
Pay Review 2016

I am pleased to advise you that your salary will be increased to  £ <?BASE_SALARY_NEW?> from 1st Jan 2016.
<?end if?>

<?IF: COMP_2_ELIGIBILITY_STATUS='N' OR  COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR= ‘Unsatisfactory’ COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR?> = ' '?>
Annual Bonus 2016
On this occasion you have not been awarded a bonus.
<?end if?>


<?IF: COMP_2_ELIGIBILITY_STATUS='Y' AND COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR != ' Unsatisfactory'?>
Annual Bonus 2016

You have been awarded a Annual bonus of £<?COMP_2_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT?>. This will be paid during 1st Feb 2016.

A number of factors have been taken into account to determine your final bonus including; performance against objectives, overall company performance and target bonus %. 
<?end if?>

At Xyz we have always been committed to ensuring that our pay is competitive and we pay our employees appropriately for the role that they do.  

Congratulations and best wishes for 2017.


Yours sincerely


<?PRIMARY_MANAGER?>

<?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>

<? split-by-page-break:?><?end for-each?>
```

But when i am validating it I am getting the following error. The tag seems to be okay. Tried everything still getting teh same error

```
[082816_215752750][][ERROR] [Line 2006.6] Incorrect XPath: COMP_3_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT='' and COMP COMP_2_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT=''
[082816_215752790][][ERROR] [Line 2069.34] Incorrect XPath: COMP_2_ELIGIBILITY_STATUS='N' OR  COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR= ‘Unsatisfactory’ COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR
[082816_215752798][][ERROR] [Line 2086.166] Incorrect XPath: COMP_2_ELIGIBILITY_STATUS='Y' AND COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR != ' Unsatisfactory'
```

The problem seems to be with the null tags . Can some one tell me how can we write if an expression is null or is there any other thing i am doing incorrectly in the above template.

Comment: Looks like an extra `COMP` after the `and` on line 2006.6 - `COMP COMP_2_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?choose:?>
<?when:COMP_3_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT='' and COMP_2_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT='' ?>
No Letter has been generated for this employee as they were not eligible for a pay or bonus review and did not receive any share awards.

Plan:           <?PLAN_NAME?>
Period:         <?PERIOD_NAME?>
Name:           <?NAME?>
Person Number:  <?PERSON_NUMBER?>
<?end when?>
<?otherwise:?>

<?NAME?>                                            
Person Number : <?PERSON_NUMBER?>
<?CURRENT_JOB?>

Dear <?FIRST_NAME?>,

<?if: COMP_4_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT=''?>
Pay Review 2016

On this occasion you have not been awarded a salary increase. Your salary will remain at £ <?BASE_SALARY_CURRENT?> per annum.
<?end if?>

<?if: COMP_4_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT!=''?>
Pay Review 2016

I am pleased to advise you that your salary will be increased to  £ <?BASE_SALARY_NEW?> from 1st Jan 2016.
<?end if?>

<?if: COMP_2_ELIGIBILITY_STATUS = 'N' or COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR ='Unsatisfactory' or COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR = ''?>
Annual Bonus 2016
On this occasion you have not been awarded a bonus.
<?end if?>


<?if:COMP_2_ELIGIBILITY_STATUS='Y' and COMP_PERF_RATING_DESCR != 'Unsatisfactory'?>
Annual Bonus 2016

You have been awarded a Annual bonus of £<?COMP_2_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT?>. This will be paid during 1st Feb 2016.

A number of factors have been taken into account to determine your final bonus including; performance against objectives, overall company performance and target bonus %. 
<?end if?>

At Xyz we have always been committed to ensuring that our pay is competitive and we pay our employees appropriately for the role that they do.  

Congratulations and best wishes for 2017.


Yours sincerely


<?PRIMARY_MANAGER?>

<?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>

<? split-by-page-break:?>
```

There were some syntax issues, extra and missing tags. I think the AND and OR operators are case sensitive. The code above passes validation on my side.